# Access Lion SMB shares from Linux

Tags: macos, unix, server.app, smb

I have this fantastic new Lion server that I've gotten all setup with my user accounts, files, etc. File sharing is up and running, everything. Except for one problem: the users running Linux (we use both Linux and OS X clients) cannot authenticate and access the SMB shares.
All of the users' accounts are setup as network accounts (i.e. in Open Directory not the local user database)

Interestingly enough, if the user account is setup as a local account (not Open Directory) the user can authenticate just fine. And we can't switch away from Open Directory because we use the LDAP authentication for some of our other tools.

Does anyone have any ideas on what to do to get this working? I've been pulling my hair out trying.

Comment: Some old information - 10.6 stores passwords by default with different salt/enxcryption than SMB and it always asked to re-enter the password so it could be stored in the SMB format. The Lion documentation is still rolling out. Are the linux clients bound to the Lion directory or another AD server? http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3888

Comment: Since something is storing the passwords properly when a local user is created, it might be a bug (or just bad documentation) - You can ask AppleCare for support on this within the 90 day new OS window without needing a paid contract. AppleCare for the mac mini server does include GUI administration tasks so this should be in scope for them even if it has to get escalated to the server trained staff.

Comment: Some of the machines are bound to the Lion directory, while others are completely unbound. There's not a bit of Windows anywhere in the network, so no active directory to interfere with anything. The interesting thing is that bound/unbound Macs can authenticate just fine it is only the Linux machines which suggests a different authentication scheme is being used but I can't figure out what or how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Samba no more, for Lion Server [mount.cifs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) needs [extra options](http://blog.earth-works.com/2012/11/11/mounting-smb-shares-hosted-on-mac-os-x-from-linux/), "nounix,sec=ntlmssp"

---

```
  [root@50centos ~]# 
  [root@50centos ~]# yum install samba-client samba-common cifs-utils
 ...
  [root@50centos ~]# mkdir /mnt/lion_smb
  [root@50centos ~]# mount -t cifs -o MikeCochran,trustno1,nounix,sec=ntlmssp //198.252.206.140/smb_share /mnt/lion_smb/

          =^..^=       `·.¸¸ ><((((º>.·´¯`·><((((º>   

MikeCochran@stack:~$ 
MikeCochran@stack:~$ sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
  ...
MikeCochran@stack:~$ mkdir /mnt/lion_smb
MikeCochran@stack:~$ mount.cifs //198.252.206.140/smb_share /mnt/lion_smb/ -o user=MikeCochran,password=trustno1,nounix,sec=ntlmssp
MikeCochran@stack:~$ 
MikeCochran@stack:~$ mkdir /mnt/lion_smb_dup
MikeCochran@stack:~$ mount -t cifs //198.252.206.140/smb_share /mnt/lion_smb-dup -o username=MikeCochran,password=trustno1,nounix,sec=ntlmssp
```

---

apologies for the delay!!